# How to connect WSO2 and hashicorp vault for oidc discovery

Tags: hashicorp-vault, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure hashicorp vault to use wso2is as an identity provider. My preferred solution for now is to configure OIDC discovery url belonging to wso2. My current setup is vault and wso2 both locally installed and accessible on https://localhost:

A certificate issue and authorisation are my current stumbling blocks.
On vault the oidc discovery url is "https://localhost:9443", which throws up this error (error checking discovery URL: error creating provider with given values: Get https://localhost:9443/well-known/openid-configuration:x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

Answer (score 0):

You would not find a better answer than this[1]!.

Please follow it. If you have any questions regarding the article, please add them here.

[1] https://medium.com/identity-unlocked/authenticate-with-vault-by-hashicorp-using-wso2-identity-server-ba87f61444c2